# Django Admin - save_model method - How to detect if a field has changed?

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to override the [save_model method on a Django admin object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) to prevent a user from changing a certain field.  However I can't find a way to find out if the field has changed within this method.

Here's my code so far:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if change: 
        if obj.parking_location == form.cleaned_data['parking_location']:
            super(MyVehiclesAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 
                "The Parking Location field cannot be changed.")
```

The problem is both obj.parking_location, and form.cleaned_data['parking_location'] have the new value.  (Could this be a bug in Django?  It really seems like the obj should contain the pre-save values).  In any case, is there another way to accomplish this?

(I'm on Django 1.2)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Firstly, this isn't a bug, it's the documented behaviour in Django 1.2 onwards.

From the [Django 1.2 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#modelform-is-valid-and-modelform-errors):

> the first time you call `ModelForm.is_valid()`, access `ModelForm.errors` or otherwise trigger form validation, your model will be cleaned in-place. This conversion used to happen when the model was saved. If you need an unmodified instance of your model, you should pass a copy to the ModelForm constructor.

If you want to prevent the user from editing a paticular field, a better approach might be to use the [`ModelAdmin.readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields) option.

```
class VehicleRegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('parking_location',)
```

Or, you could replace the `ModelAdmin.form` with a custom form that excludes that field.

```
class VehicleRegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        exclude = ('parking_location',)

class VehicleRegistrationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = VehicleRegistrationForm
```

Finally, to answer your question more directly, you can check whether a field has changed in the `save_model` method by inspecting `form.changed_data`. This is a list of the names of the fields which have changed.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if 'parking_location' in form.changed_data:
        messages.info(request, "Parking location has changed")
    else:
        messages.info(request, "Parking location has not changed")
    super(MyVehiclesAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Comment: Oh, yeah! `form.changed_data` is the way to do it via the `ModelAdmin`'s `save_model` method. Thank you. +1 from me :)

Answer (score 43):

For those wondering about the `change` parameter:

This parameter will be True if this is a change on an existing model, it is False if the model is a newly created instance.

To check whether any fields have been changed: `form.changed_data` will contain the changed fields which means that it is empty if there are no changes.

Comment: Thanks for this. This should be in the docs (specifically what the change parameter does.)

Answer (score 9):

Ok, I found a work-around.  This still seems like a bug to me though.

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if change: 
        vr = VehicleRegistration.objects.get(pk=obj.id)
        if vr.parking_location == form.cleaned_data['parking_location']:
            super(MyVehiclesAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        else:
            messages.error(request, 
                "The Parking Location field cannot be changed.")
```

Comment: poor design decision != bug ;)

Comment: this is a great way if you want to check the previous value and new value

Answer (score 3):

you can always find the value from the db with `MyVehicles.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)`