# How to call models.py save() method before admin.py save_model() method when saving the model from django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Whenever I am changing the data in django admin interface, admin.py `save_model()` method is getting called first.

I want to call models.py save() method before admin.py `save_model()` method, when I am saving the data from django admin interface. How can I do it?

Actually I am debugging some code and there it is happening and I am not able to identify the reason!

Comment: Have you tried django signal `pre_save`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#pre-save

Comment: @ShangWang `pre_save` signal is also called after `save_model()`

Comment: Why do you want to call it first?

Comment: Can you override the save_model() like: [Save_model admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056179/django-admin-save-model-method-how-to-detect-if-a-field-has-changed)

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. `save_model` is the thing that actually *calls* `save`, as you can see [from the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L999). Since you can override the save_model method, there doesn't seem to be any reason to want anything else to be called first.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually I am debugging some code and there it is happening, that's why I am asking how can it be possible?